Discord.js Bot V14 - AuditLogs not returning right data on specific events
I'm trying to make a small Logger Discord Bot. The code below is how i get the audit logs entry (for the channelDelete event).
But i got a big problem: also if the user who deletes the message (user A) is not a bot or the author of the message (user B), the executor (and also the target) is not correct, it's referred to a previous deleted message (the channel data is about the right deleted channel).
Example: user A create a message -> User B deletes it.
Then user B creates a message -> User A deletes it.
Both logs have as executor user B and target User A (waited until the end of an action before to perform an other)
I've also ried to add a setTimeout(() => {...}, 2500); But nothing changes, it doesn't give the right executor (and target).
What i'm doing wrong?
    const AuditLogFetch = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
      limit: 1,
      type: auditType,
    });
    if (!AuditLogFetch.entries.first())
      return console.error(`No entries found.`);

    const entry = AuditLogFetch.entries.first();
    let parentChannel = null;
    if (entry.channelParentId) 
      parentChannel =                                                       channel.guild.channels.cache.get(channel.parentId).toString();

    const chDeleteEmbed = {
      color: colors.DARK_RED,
      author: {
       name: `${entry.globalName != null ? entry.globalName : 'No nickname'} [${entry.username != null ? entry.username : 'No username'}]`,
        icon_url: entry.displayAvatarURL()
      },
      description: `${channel.type} deleted by <@${entry.executor.id}> \n 
        ${parentChannel != null ? `In category: ${parentChannel}` : '' }`,
      fields: [
        { 
          name: 'Nome canale', 
          value: `${channel.name}`
        }
      ],
     }
     // send embed func ...
  })

Thank you

If i understood your question right you might be able to use entry.createdTimestamp > Date.now() - 1000 when you fetch your latest MessageDelete log to make sure its the latest deleted message and not a previous one that was logged

THe problem is that i've only 1 entry in the entries of the GuildAuditLogs, and it's taken wrong from the previous action. But also with date check nothing changes for because the new audit it's not into the entries.
Or with more details, it tooks the right channel info, but not the executor and it took an old executor

well then thats the problem with your code your always getting latest log and theres going to be scenarios where there wont be logs popping up in the audit log such as a user deleting their own message, you'll have to add some handling in your code to determine who the executors are
